# ¿Cómo determinar si el dispositivo es orientable?

Tags: javascript

Actualmente uso el siguiente código para detectar el tamaño de la pantalla:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="FSAUX" style="height:1em;width:1em;left:100%;position:fixed;top:100%;"></div>
    <div id="CMAUX" style="height:1cm;width:1cm;left:100%;position:fixed;top:100%;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
SCREEN = {
  FBS: document.getElementById( 'FSAUX' ).offsetWidth,
  CENTS: screen.width / document.getElementById( 'CMAUX' ).offsetWidth,
  CHARS: screen.width / document.getElementById( 'FSAUX' ).offsetWidth,
  WIDTH: screen.width
};

if( ( SCREEN.WIDTH < 800 ) ||
    ( SCREEN.CENTS < 10 ) ||
    ( SCREEN.CHARS < 80 ) ) {
  document.title = 'Pantalla pequeña';
} else {
  document.title = 'Pantalla grande';
}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Establezco unos tamaños mínimos de varios factores: puntos, centímetros, y tamaño base de las fuentes. Dependiendo de lo anterior cargo una u otra versión de mi aplicación. Una vez *cargada* una versión, **no puedo** cargar otra. Tienen *interfaces* muy distintos y no implementan las mismas características.

El problema surge en dispositivos *orientables* o *girables*. Dependiendo de la orientación (horizontal/vertical) obtengo unos u otros valores de pantalla.

Ello conlleva que *cargue* la versión para pantallas pequeñas, cuando en realidad al usuario le bastaría con *girar* el dispositivo, colocándolo en horizontal para poder usar la versión para pantallas *grandes*.

**No** quiero detectar el navegador. **Sólo** me interesa saber si el dispositivo es o no *orientable*.

¿Hay alguna forma de comprobarlo en Javascript? Preferiblemente *puro*; Si se necesita alguna librería ya buscaré en su código como lo implementa.

Comment: Buenas! [igual esto te puede ayudar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917664/detect-viewport-orientation-if-orientation-is-portrait-display-alert-message-ad) (no se si lo habrás mirado)

Comment: @lois6b gracias, no lo había mirado (no *atinaba* con los términos en inglés). A ver si me sirve :-)

Comment: @lois6b no, no me sirve. Indica varias formas de obtener el tamaño de la ventana/pantalla, pero ... no indica si esta puede ser *girada*. Los cambios de tamaño ya los contemplo (es una app *responsiva*). El asunto es que hay 2 versiones **muy distintas** entre si, y no puedo cambiar de una a otra una vez que *elija* una. Si el dispositivo es *orientable*, puedo comprobar si el ancho o el alto tienen un mínimo ... pero necesito saber que es orientable; que los tamaños pueden ser intercambiados.

Comment: Entiendo... Entonces por qué no detectas el dispositivo que se está usando? Si es movil o tablet será orientable no¿?

Comment: @lois6b ya lo había pensado, y es lo que haré como último recurso, pero ... y si usan un navegador *no contemplado* en los chequeos de *user-agent* ? tendría que hacer cambios en la aplicación, y me parece una solución mas ... *sucia*. Por preguntar, que no quede :-)

Comment: mhh  y [que tal esto](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33843234/3045491)?. Ahi no detecta giros si no que detecta si tiene giroscopio

Comment: @lois6b interesante :-). Lo probaré. Y un *media-query* que he encontrado, `handheld`, que indica si el dispositivo es *de mano*. Tardaré algo en las pruebas, pero publicaré los resultados :-)

Comment: @Trauma `@media handheld` no te va a funcionar. La mayoría de los celulares modernos toman el CSS `screen`.

Comment: @Mariano gracias por el *toque*. Estoy intentando mezclar tu respuesta, los comentarios de lois6b, y todo lo que pillo por ahí, pero me da que no va a salir nada en claro; al final, si el usuario tiene el movil vertical, que lo gire y recargue la página. P'a que *espabile* ;-)

Comment: ¿Y si fuerzas al usuario a que gire el dispositivo? Detectar si es orientable o no, no tiene mucha utilidad en sí, importa más si cambia la orientación una vez cargada la página ¿no?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro te equivocas. Una vez cargada una versión de la app, no importa si lo gira o no. La app se ajusta. Lo que no puedo es *descargar* una para *cargar* la otra, porque no son equivalentes. Si la pantalla es pequeña, y no gira, cargo la versión *mini*. Si la pantalla es pequeña, pero **si** gira, cargo la versión *full*. Ya lo girará el usuario cuando vea que no puede ver toda la info.

Comment: Sé que voy a sonar mal, pero (con los pocos datos con los que cuento) lo que describes parece un mal diseño a punto de convertirse en pesadilla

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro y, posiblemente, lo sea :-( es que la versión *full* hace cosas que requieren cierto tamaño de la pantalla, mientras que la *mini* es solo para consultas ocasionales. Concretamente, es una app de stocks de almacen y albaranes. Se usará desde PC, pero, si quieren los *jefazos*, pueden hacer consultas desde el móvil. Uso 3 archivos fuente: core.js, full.js, mini.js. Cargo siempre el core.js, y dependiendo del tamaño de la pantall, el full.js o el mini.js. En la full, tinen menús y cosas *guapas*. La mini, solo una serie de listas de acciones. No son equiparables.

Comment: Pfff. Te estaba escribiendo una respuesta sobre orientación de pantalla en JavaScript, pero no sé si te va a servir de mucho ahora... :S

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, siempre puedes darle +1 a la pregunta jejeje. El tema de la orientación está solucionado, lo hace todo `webix`, la librería `.js` que uso. El *dilema* es decidir que versión cargar, la *mini*, o la *full*. Una vez hecho el login, hay que salir y volver a entrar para cambiar de versión.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existe una API web encargada de la orientación de pantalla ([Screen Orientation API](https://w3c.github.io/screen-orientation/)) que te permite leer el tipo y ángulo de la orientación, saber si hay cambios en la misma, e incluso "bloquear" los cambios de orientación.

El principal problema es que es experimental y no está ampliamente soportada. En dispositivos de escritorio las últimas versiones de casi todos los navegadores lo permiten (menos Safari), aunque puede que necesites usar prefijos (ver abajo). Y en dispositivos móviles, Chrome y Firefox Mobile sí... pero poco más.

Con esta API se puede:

- [Detectar la orientación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation) del dispositivo:

  ```
  var orientacionPantalla = window.screen.orientation.type;
  ```

  Como es una tecnología experimental, puede que necesites usar prefijos de dispositivo, algo como esto (descrito en el enlace de esta sección):

  ```
  var orientation = screen.orientation || screen.mozOrientation || screen.msOrientation;
  var orientacionPantalla = orientation.type;
  ```

  La variable `orientacion` tendrá entonces uno de los siguientes valores (en la página enlazada viene un ejemplo de cómo podría utilizarse para pedir al usuario que cambie la orientación si no es una de las que quieres):

  - "landscape-primary"
  - "landscape-secondary"
  - "portrait-primary"
  - "portrait-secondary"
- [Bloquear la orientación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/lockOrientation) del dispositivo con `lockOrientation`:

  ```
  bloqueoPermitido = window.screen.lockOrientation(orientacion);
  ```

  Esto te permitiría bloquear la pantalla en alguno de los modos que quieras (los listados arriba). Puede ser un valor sólo o un array. Aquí dejo un ejemplo para forzar a que la orientación de pantalla se quede en modo apaisado:

  ```
  screen.lockOrientationUniversal = screen.lockOrientation || screen.mozLockOrientation || screen.msLockOrientation;

  if (screen.lockOrientationUniversal("landscape-primary")) {
      // la orientación se pudo bloquear
  } else {
      // la orientación no se pudo bloquear
  }
  ```
- [Detectar cambios de orientación](https://w3c.github.io/screen-orientation/#h-examples): podrías seguir haciéndolo con `onorientationchange`, pero esta API añade una posibilidad más al permitir asociar un controlador del evento `change` a la orientación de pantalla (`screen.orientation`).

  Algo como esto:

  ```
  screen.orientation.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
       // código a ejecutar cuando se cambie la orientación
  });
  ```

Comprendo que no puedes exactamente detectar si el dispositivo es orientable (que es lo que preguntas), pero sí puedes detectar la orientación y entonces mostrar un mensaje diciéndole al usuario "Sería mejor que rotaras el dispositivo" o *forzarle* a que lo rote girando todo el contenido para lo que quieres.

Comment: @Mariano tienes razón, no importaría cuál usar, y teniendo en cuenta el bajo soporte de la API, `onorientationchange` es seguramente más recomendada en este momento

Comment: Excelente resumen de una API que no está tan bien documentada! Para ver compatibilidad con navegadores: http://caniuse.com/#feat=screen-orientation

Comment: Escondida, pero das la respuesta clave: `no puedes exactamente detectar si el dispositivo es orientable`. Faltaría la coletilla `con API no` *deprecated*.

Answer (score 4):

> Ello conlleva **que cargue la versión para pantallas pequeña**s, cuando en realidad al usuario le bastaría con girar el dispositivo, colocándolo en horizontal para poder usar **la versión para pantallas grandes**.

Iniciando ya tienes un problema. Tener una versión para móviles y otra para escritorio es un desgaste innecesario de tiempo. Con la aparición de la tendencia del diseño responsivo, esto debería pasar a la historia.

> Me interesa saber si el dispositivo es o no orientable. ¿Hay alguna forma de comprobarlo en Javascript?

Sí, es posible. No solo es posible saber si es orientable, si no también *la orientación* del dispositivo (portrait o landscape). La propiedad [`window#orientation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientation) te devuelve por lo general los valores:

- -90/bottom
- 0/left
- 90/right
- 180/top

Estos dos últimos valores pueden cambiar dependiendo del dispositivo, por lo que debes tener cuidado.

Por ejemplo, los Apple Touch interpreta el último valor commo -90, mientras que Google Nexus lo interpreta como 90, lo que **no te permitirá saber** si el dispositivo está echado **cara abajo**. Puede que no lo veas necesario en general, pero es mejor que si alguna vez lo necesitas, te muestre un valor estándar para todos. Otro ejemplo de ésto son las tablets Toshiba: la mayoría de series te mostrará 180 si lo echas cara abajo, cuando lo lógico es que sea -90, como sí lo hace Google o Amazon.

Si necesitas saber la orientación del dispositivo, puede serte útil [`window#screen.orientation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation) cuya propiedad `type`, te permite saber la orientación del dispositivo, las cuales son:

- portrait-primary
- portrait-secondary
- landscape-primary
- landscape-secondary

El primary/secondary sirve para interpretar si está 'al revés' o no.

---

**Nota:** La propiedad `window#orientation` solo estará disponible en dispositivos que soporten orientación.

Answer (score 1):

```js
if (typeof window.orientation !== 'undefined') {
    //El dispositivo puede rotarse
    //...
}
```

- [window.orientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/window/orientation) es una propiedad **obsoleta** que funciona en la mayoría de los navegadores.
- En dispositivos que se pueden rotar, devuelve 0, 90, -90 o 180 (el ángulo de orientación actual). En el resto, devuelve undefined.
- Es una manera sencilla, que no depende del tamaño de la pantalla ni en el userAgent, pero deberías probar que funciona en los navegadores en los que quieras usarlo.